# File Won't Save to Variable Folder

Tags: excel, vba, mkdir, save-as

I am trying to create a record for training that employees complete. I have the forms set to create a folder with their employee number and then save the file with the training title. However, it is erroring out on my saveas line of code... not sure what is missing or wrong...

```
    Sub submitgen()

    Dim empnum As String
    Dim traintype As String

    empnum = Sheets("GENERAL TRAINING").Range("E7").Value
    traintype = Sheets("GENERAL TRAINING").Range("E13").Value

    If Len(Dir("C:\Emily\test\" & empnum, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
      MkDir "C:\Emily\test\" & empnum
    End If

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Emily\test\" & empnum & "\" & traintype, FileFormat:=52

    End Sub
```

What'd I mess up folks?

Comment: What is the error message, and the values of `empnum` and `traintype`?

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the `SaveAs` line (F9), then run the code; when the breakpoint is hit, bring up the Immediate pane (Ctrl+G) and type `?"C:\Emily\test\" & empnum & "\" & traintype` -- if that's not a legal path + file name, that might be why it's blowing up (what's the error exactly?). In particular, watch for doubled-up backslashes (does `traintype` include a file extension?).

Comment: Can you post the expected Full path of the workbook after it's saved?

Comment: Just before the SaveAs,  Add Debug.Print "C:\Emily\test\" & empnum & "\" & traintype

Comment: @ladymrt Your code saves file .It creates a Subfolder with `empnum` in `"C:\Emily\test\"` , then it saves the active workbook renaming it with value of `E13 ` and extension of active workbook.

Comment: "Run-time error '1004': Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed

Comment: empnum should just be a normal number 2 or 3 digits long. traintype could potentially be more than one word but I've tested it with just one word, no merge area and it still gives me this error. It's creating the folder, it's just not saving the file.

Comment: Well the cell reference for the training type was wrong. Dumb mistake. Thanks for trying guys!

Comment: please always refer to comment giving person like @xxxx to enable automatic transmission of alerts to commenting person so that they can respond quickly to your responses. In your case we did not get any alerts.